# Swaping a default div with another onclick

Tags: jquery, css

I would like a div onload to have some content and some other divs available but not visible on load. When I click a given link it will hide the current showing div and make that div visible.

```
<div class="current">
    This is here by default 
</div>

<div class="link 1 hidden">
    Link 1 info
</div>

<div class="link 2 hidden">
    Link 2 info
</div>

<div class="link 3 hidden">
    Link 3 info
</div>

<div class="link 4 hidden">
    Link 4 info
</div>
```

Comment: Qu'est-ce qu'on a essayé?

Comment: Please describe the  **specific** problem you're having while trying to do that.

Comment: I'm trying to hide the default div and show the div associated to the link. jsfiddle.net/daniellefrappier/3q44f5eu/#

Answer (score 0):

A very simple way to do that is using the **:target** pseudo class in your CSS.

You can see an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/t4hoff4c/

You have to assign the same id to the nav link and to the section.

**HTML**

```
 <li><a href="#one">First Paragraph</a></li>

 <section id="one">
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur ...
 </section>
```

**CSS**

```
section:target{
  display:block;
}

section{
  display:none;
}
```

Eventually you can use some Javascript in order to assign a default active class when the page loads. Hope that helps.

Comment: thank you for the fiddle, that always makes stuff much easier to understand.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to make the class "default" in this example display none when you click on any of this links? http://jsfiddle.net/daniellefrappier/3q44f5eu/#

Comment: Here it is a little closer but still not working. http://jsfiddle.net/daniellefrappier/g5w9hpa9/#&togetherjs=3mgDnFS9Vl

Comment: After including jQuery in your fiddle i was able to see only the default class when the page loads. Then clicking on QLD i see only tab2, and clicking on VIC i see only tab3. Isn't that the behavior you are trying to achieve?